# Java Decimal Format issue zero (0.00)

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have a problem with the formatter, when I give a 0.00 return +0,00 E but I would like to 0,00 E.

```
String PATTERN = "###,##0.00\u00a0\u00A4";
DecimalFormatSymbols SYMBOLS = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
DecimalFormat FORMATTER_SIGN = new DecimalFormat(PATTERN, SYMBOLS);
FORMATTER_SIGN.setNegativePrefix("-\u00a0");
FORMATTER_SIGN.setPositivePrefix("+\u00a0");
FORMATTER_SIGN.format("0.00") // this
```

Comment: FORMATTER_SIGN.format(0)

Comment: I do not want only to zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own DecimalFormat that is aware of zeros (simplified example):

```
class ZeroAwareDecimalFormat extends DecimalFormat {
    private final DecimalFormat zeroFormat;

    public ZeroAwareDecimalFormat(String posNegPattern, String zeroPattern) {
        super(posNegPattern);
        zeroFormat = new DecimalFormat(zeroPattern);
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer result, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        if (number == 0L) {
            return zeroFormat.format(number, result, fieldPosition);
        } else {
            return super.format(number, result, fieldPosition);
        }
    }

    // Override the other methods accordingly.
    // set... methods should be propagated to super and zeroFormat.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can get rid of the "+" when I remove the line

```
FORMATTER_SIGN.setPositivePrefix("+\u00a0");
```

or change it to

```
FORMATTER_SIGN.setPositivePrefix("");
```

Resulting in

> 0,00 €

PS: Your `format` call doesn't work for me, I need to do something like this:

```
FORMATTER_SIGN.format(Double.valueOf("0.00")); // this
```

Comment: for a number greater than zero, plus should appear.
eg 
0,00 
+ 12,43
- 232,54
+ 5 435,33

Comment: @Tomas well that's a critical piece of requirement missing from your question.